# show popupcontrol  in rowupdating event of devexpress gridview, if a certain criteria fails

Tags: devexpress

I have a Devexpress Gridview where item and it's price is displayed.

Editing is enabled.

I use rowupdating event so inorder to check if the price updated is higher than a normal value.

if so,  i cancel edit by

```
e.Cancel = true;
 ASPxGridView1.CancelEdit();
```

the next thing i want is to popup a aspx popupcontrol  requesting a password inorder to proceed with higher amount within the rowupdating event.

the popcontrol will contain a password textbox and a button.The remaining procces will be carried out by button click function

eventhough i called popcontrol

```
 ASPxPopupControl2.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
```

the pop doesn't show up......why is this so..

here is my over all code..

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    string msg;

    double new_amt = double.Parse(e.NewValues["Amount"].ToString());//-->gets new amount

    string type= e.OldValues["Type"].ToString();//-->gets the item

    double refer_amt=Misc_functions.Get_Item_Amount(type,out msg);//--this function fetches the normal amount for a particular item

    if (new_amt > refer_amt)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        ASPxGridView1.CancelEdit();

        ASPxPopupControl2.ShowOnPageLoad = true;

    }


}
```

Basically i need a password authentication if an amount edited is a higher than a normal value.
any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done using the server code.  The best solution is to create a custom java script variable within the RowUpdating event handler and check its value in the ASPxGridView's client side EndCallback event handler.  I.e.

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{ ...
   gridView.JSProperties["cpShowPopup"] = true;
...
}

EndCallback = function(s,e) { 
  if(typeof(s.cpShowPopup) != 'undefined') { 
    popup.Show();
  }
}
```

Hope, this helps.